# Efficiently return an updated object in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Many times in Python I do this :

- create an object;
- use a common method of this object to update it;
- return the updated object for immediate usage;
- never us it again.

A toy example would be as below :

```
haystack = set(xrange(1, 10))
needle = np.random.randint(20)
haystack.add(needle)

print haystack
```

Now what I am looking for is the most efficient (and somewhat pythonic way) of one-lining the above process.

A solution could be to define beforehead a function for doing this :

```
def value(object, method, *args):
    getattr(object, method)(*args)
    return object
```

So I can do something like this whenever I want :

```
print value(set(xrange(1, 10)), "add", np.random.randint(1, 20))

>> set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 17])
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: I think you might have abstracted that too far. You have to write as much for `value` as you do for the original version! Why not e.g. `create_haystack((1, 10), (1, 20))`?

Comment: `value` represents the function I'm looking for, ideally in Python common resources. If I don't find it with this post, I think I could put this value function in a `own_utils` module I can call for most of my quick producted projects. So I don't want it to be specific, exactly like I don't want a too specific answer for this problem. It's more like a general purpose question : the `set/add` thing is just a toy example.

Comment: But my point is that if you make it too abstract you just end up writing as much code to pass into it as you're trying to save, suggesting it's the wrong level of abstraction. And this cannot be answered in the general case, the answer is *"it depends"*.

Comment: It's the good level of abstraction since it does exactly what I demand : allowing me to include the created+updated object in a more general expression. In the contrary, I can't one-line the first code sample. If this `value` function was part of Python commons, it would answer this question. Being more specific won't, as well as suggesting the first sample.

Comment: Well, if you're absolutely convinced that you need a function to *"instantiate a given class with given positional arguments then call a given method on the instance with more given positional arguments"* then your current version is roughly fine. I might be inclined to handle keyword arguments too, accept a list of methods to call in order and maybe use `functools.partial` to do some of the work for me, but YMMV. But that still doesn't leave us with a specific, useful SO question, so I see no point discussing it further.

Comment: The point is not necessarily to instantiate the class, but have a sort of wrapper to get the value of the new instance given by one of its methods instead of the common `None` following side effects.

Comment: I edited the example result to stress this.

Comment: But that's the convention in the language you're using; either return a new object or mutate the old one and don't return anything. If you want a "fluent interface" model, consider e.g. Java. If you want your code reviewed maybe see [codereview.se], but they don't accept snippets. You still don't have an SO question here.

Comment: Not sure about your third bullet point, but if you do want to return a class instance, simply `return self` at the end of the method. Not the usual way to do that in Python though, but you could then indeed to `print(haystack.add(needle))`.

Comment: Java is not as handy as Python when it comes to data sciences, and some Python objects have this kind of feature (e.g. `dict.setdefault`). I don't see why I should drop the language instead of finding an aesthetic solution to the particular inconvenience.

Comment: @Evert You mean re-writing the underlying class (`set` in the toy example) ? It seems a bit brutal.

Comment: @Thrastylon not necessarily re-writing, you could subclass it (`class FluentSet(set):`) and implement wrappers around the original methods. Note that `dict.setdefault` returns *the value*, not the dictionary itself. *"an aesthetic solution"* is necessarily opinion-based, hence not on-topic here.